Interval scheduling maximization problem (ISMP) variation with flexible start time and common deadline
I'm trying to find an optimal algorithm for ISMP variation, with 2 additional details: the start of any interval can be moved forward and there's a common 'deadline' for all intervals.
Given:

Set of intervals: start, end - a_i, b_i.
Deadline - D (same for all intervals)
a_i - can be moved forward up until D

Goal: Find the maximum number of non-overlapping intervals.
